# PHP MySQL Query; Max Execution Time and Memory Limit don't work on browser output

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache

So I am using a form with a file input to submit an excel file and upload the data into a MySQL database. The script imports everything just fine.

Only problem is that the process seems to timeout on the client browser, even though it seems to continue it's process on the server, but it seems to timeout on the client browser. I have already added all the common fixes, I.E.:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
set_time_limit(0);      
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ignore_user_abort(true);
```

I am currently using a flush(); and ob_end_flush(); to output a message every 1000 records that get scanned for upload.

Unfortunately, after exactly 2 minutes, the page stops loading.

On the flip side, it does continue to upload the records all records get scanned and uploaded regardless of the page. This leads me to believe that somehow the request is continuing to process on the web server, but somehow the browser stops getting info from the server after a certain amount of time. Based on my calculations, the browser stops getting the request after exactly 2 minutes.

I have tried this on both Internet Explorer and Chrome and I get the same result. I have not made any changes to the php.ini file for the security reasons.

Using Old Zend Server with Apache2.

Comment: I would check what Apache2's timeout it set at.  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#timeout

Comment: No, this does not help. Thank you though.